# How i can control whether a char[] is null?

Tags: java

I wrote  this code to control whether a char[] is null or not.

```
char[] xxx = new char[9]; 

for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        {
            if (xxx[i]==null)   
            {
                xxx[i]=i; 
            }
 }
```

Comment: This code alone means nothing. What are you trying to do in a larger context? Can you give us a decent snippet of code (with variable `declarations` too)?

Comment: The values in a `char[]` cannot be null; they're primitive values.  The array itself can be null, though.

Comment: I edit my question. Now it is clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (xxx[i]==0)
this code works.0 means that in char is null.try it.

Answer (score 3):

Each element of a `char[]` is a `char`, which is a primitive type.  Primitive types cannot be `null`, so your comparison will never return `true`.  If you say more about what you are trying to accomplish, you may get some useful advice about how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

What is `char[]` in your example? if `_board` is a `char[]` then you are checking if one of the `char` is null, chars can't be null since char is a primitive type.

I'm guessing you should do

```
if (_board == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the word "control" in a confusing way.

Your code will test if `_board[i]` is null.  It is correct in that sense.  It might fail if

- `_board` was not defined.
- `i` was not defined.
- `_board` is not an array
- `_board` is not an array of objects (only object references can be null)

It will "work" but not "do anything" if `_board[i]` is not null.